# Помогите оптимизировать и улучшить js код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода, localstorage, рефакторинг

При нажатии на ссылку записывается `id` в localStorage, а если `id` присутствует в localStorage то добавляется класс `views` к ссылке с `id`. Таких ссылок на странице много, `{news-id}` это номер номер ссылки(трека).

Назначение этого кода: Чтобы пользователи визуально видели какие треки они прослушали.

Посмотрите код по взрослому так сказать и зачем здесь класс `play_list`? Может без него можно как обойтись?

```
<div class="play_list">
    <a href="#" class="play" id="Player{news-id}">Включить трек</a> 
</div>
```

js

```
var views = {
save: function(b) {
    var a = localStorage['level'];
    a = a ? JSON.parse(a) : new Object;

    var i = a[b] ? a[b] : new Object;
    i[b] = b;
    a[b] = i;

    if (b && !$('#Player' + b).hasClass('views')) {
        $('#Player' + b).addClass('views');
        localStorage['level'] = JSON.stringify(a);

        console.log('#Player' + b + ' addClass views');
    }
},
check: function(b) {
    var a = localStorage['level'];
    a = a ? JSON.parse(a) : new Object;

    $(b).find('a').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');

        if (a[id]) {
            $('#Player' + id).addClass('views');

            console.log('#Player' + id + ' addClass views');
        }
    });
}
}

views.check('.play_list');

$(function() {
$('.play').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');
    views.save(id);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.clear').click(function(e) {
    localStorage['level'] = '';
    $('.play_list').find('a').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('Player', '');

        if (id && $('#Player' + id).hasClass('views')) {
            $('#Player' + id).removeClass('views');

            console.log('#Player' + id + ' removeClass views');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Забыл ещё, здесь есть удалить всё из localStorage

Comment: а ссылки автоматически генерируются? вы можете формат их поменять, например не `id` или не только `id` выставлять но и еще какие-нибудь атрибуты?

Comment: Конечно можно, какую угодно сделать, я прописал `{news-id}` это число новости, чтоб `id` не повторялось и было привязано именно к этой ссылке. `{news-id}` это 4 разные цифры, например 3532